# Click the same page number link cause screen render not properly

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, twitter-bootstrap, pagedlist

I'm developing MVC 5 application and using MVC PagedList for paging. I load the paged data in bootstrap modal. The page number link work properly but there is a problem when I click the same page number link, the screen rendered not properly. These 3 pictures describe the problem:

(1) Initiate Screen
[image]

(2) Click Lookup button, and list of customer will be displayed
[image]

(3) After click link page 1, the screen rendered not properly
[image]

Code for the page link (modal/partial view):

```
<script>
    $(function () {
        $('#pager').on('click', 'a', function () {
            $.ajax({
                url: this.href,
                type: 'GET',
                cache: false,
                success: function (result) {
                    $('#customerContainer').html(result);
                }
            });
            return false;
        });
    });
</script>
```

Why this is can be happened and how to solve it?

Comment: by url: this.href you are rendering the same page which you are currently on. You way use different url?

Comment: @MajoB thanks for the clue, when I print `this.href`, the result is empty, but if click page 2, the value is `http://localhost:1306/CUSTTABLE/Lookup?page=2`

Answer (score 0):

Your question helped me because I had the same issue. All I did was this.
You don't need to send a blank URL.

$ (function(){

    ('#pager').on('click', function(){

         var van = this.href;
         if(van != "" && van != null)
         {
             $.ajax({
                url: this.href,
                type: 'GET',
                cache: false,
                success: function (result) {
                    $('#customer-container').html(result);
                }
            });
            return false;
         }
});

});